# How to use string format %s and '%' in the same line?

Tags: java, string

Here is simple string format and it works.

```
String format = "Your name is %s";
String text = String.format(format, "Harry");

System.out.print(text);//print "Your name is Harry"
```

But when I use "%" in the same line

```
String format = "Your name is %s, 100%point";
String name = String.format(format, "Harry");

System.out.print(name);// I want to print "Your name is Harry, 100%point"
```

I want to print "Your name is Harry, 100%point",

but it come into runtime error

```
 java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'p'
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2781)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2811)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.<init>(Formatter.java:2624)
        at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2557)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2504)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2458)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2842)
```

How to solve it.
Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape `%` with another `%`, i.e. `%%`.

```
String format = "Your name is %s, 100%%point";
String name = String.format(format, "Harry");

System.out.print(name); // I want to print "Your name is Harry, 100%point"
```

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate questions - vote them as dupe instead